# Multiple fingerprint verification in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I want to create an app in flutter. For example, I have 5 fingerprints verified on my phone and I want each finger to navigate to a particular screen in my app. Is it possible to do?

I tried much but was unable to identify how i can relate a fingerprint to particular screen

Comment: What you want is not supported by Android's biometric APIs.